# How to run Hashicorp Vault as a service on CentOS in production

Tags: vault

I'm running the latest CentOS and I need Hashicorp Vault 1.6.3 to run as a service. I'm currently using the kv/secret background, so I can use

```
Vault kv put secret/test/hello foo=bar
```

In order to store secrets. When running vault as a server, it blocks. I need the Vault server to automatically start as a service whenever the server is rebooted, it really shouldn't be blocking if possible. It's been about three years since I've used Vault so I may just be dense here.

So I guess what I need to ask is:

1. How do I start Vault when my server reboots.
2. Should it be blocking and, if no, how do I prevent this?

Comment: What does `it blocks` mean? Is it hung, does it not daemonize, is it not respoing do requests, is it yet another possible meaning of `it blocks`?

Answer (score 2):

Vault is both a service and a command line tool in the same binary. So you can keep using `vault` on the command line, and create a plain old Linux service for Vault to run. It will "block" over there, but that's what services are for.

Depending on where you are at now, you could start with [Hashicorp's intructions to configure systemd to create a Vault service](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/deployment-guide#step-3-configure-systemd).

The service should look like this

```
[Unit]
Description="HashiCorp Vault - A tool for managing secrets"
Documentation=https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3

[Service]
User=vault
Group=vault
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=read-only
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
SecureBits=keep-caps
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK
Capabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK+ep
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vault server -config=/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl
ExecReload=/bin/kill --signal HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStopSec=30
StartLimitInterval=60
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

If under "it blocks" you mean, that the Vault is sealed, so you can configure [auto-unseal on cloud platforms](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/day-one-consul/deployment-guide#auto-unseal).
Or just add auto-unsealing bash script for service startup, if you understand all the security's issues.